# .htaccess: rewrite URL with query strings

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite a URL using an .htaccess and the URL has two query strings.  Here is my raw URL:

```
http://domain.com/channel-partners/en/index.php?location=phoenix-az&name=company
```

How do I get that to be written as:

```
http://cp.domain.com/phoenix-az/company
```

Comment: You're redirecting it from a sub-domain?

Comment: No, I'm redirecting it TO a subdomain.

Comment: Rewrites work one way. It redirects from *what you want* to *what it is*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^partners/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ channel-partners/en/index.php?location=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

This will redirect URLs in the format `partners/location/name` with an optional trailing slash to the raw URL you provided. `location` and `name` can be alphanumeric, underscore, or dash characters.

**Note:** I have prefixed the URL with the literal `partners`. Without it your RewriteRule would be too loose and match nearly all requests. Feel free to change it.

#### UPDATE

To redirect from your sub-domain, the above needs to be in the .htaccess file for cp.domain.com. You'll need to modify your RewriteRule to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^partners/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ http://domain.com/channel-partners/en/index.php?location=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

However, I really don't recommend this. Link management is going to be a nightmare. You should really try to have all these links under the same domain. 301 Redirect from the sub-domain if you have to.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get an internal server error.  If I take out the "rewrite rule on" I get no error, but it doesn't redirect, either.

Comment: Is there a way to make these more general? (In reference to your comment above)